# Python. Словарь. Вопрос по поводу сравнения

Tags: python, словари, dict

Подскажите пожалуйста: как сравнить элемент в словаре?
например дан словарь

`f={'a':1,'b':2}`

Как проверить на наличие символа в словаре?

```
for value in f.items():
   #?#
```

просто из того, что писал я выдавало ошибку.

```
if f[value]==f[value+1]:
  .....
```

Comment: весьма странная проверка `if list(f.values())[0]==list(f.values())[1]`:

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы проверить наличие какогото ключа

```
f={'a':1,'b':2}
print('a' in f.keys())
```

Итерация по всем элементам

```
f={'a':1,'b':2}

for value in f.items():
  print(value)
```

Comment: Что-то не видно ни искомого символа, ни проверки этого символа в словаре: показан обход и распечатка. Формально, это если и ответ, то не на текущий вопрос, а на какой-то другой.

Comment: @AK пусть автор уточнит что надо "Как проверить на наличие символа в словаре?" - здесь каждый символ проверяет. И восстановите мою ссылку хотя бы в комментарий там

Comment: Чтобы вы и дальше до набора репутации в 50 баллов продолжали сознательно нарушать правила?

Comment: То есть лучше не дать помощь автору в виде полезной ссылки а ждать пока у меня будет 50 репутации?

Comment: Восстановил в виде комментария. Желаю успеха на ru so.

Comment: @joker первичная цель Stack Overflow — пополнение базы знаний в формате вопрос-ответ. Ответы-ссылки этому не способствуют, так как уводят знания на какой-то сторонний и потенциально ненадёжный и непостоянный ресурс. Всё остальное вторично, так что да, если лень писать развёрнутый ответ, лучше дожидаться 50 рейтинга и ограничиваться комментарием (ну или надеяться, что добрый дядя-модератор перенесёт ответ в комментарии, такое тоже бывает)

Answer (score 0):

Проверить элемент в словаре можно вот так:

```
f = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print('a' in f)
```

Чтобы избежать подобной проверки, можно воспользоваться структурой `defaultdict`.

Если сравнивать ключи во время сортировки, то стоит использовать метод `sorted(f.keys(), key=lambda key: compare_func(key))`.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос ТС?

Comment: Потому что пользователь задаёт вопрос о поиске ключа в словаре

Comment: Пожалуйста, процитируйте то место, где он это спрашивает.

Comment: "Как проверить на наличие символа в словаре?"

Comment: А что такое символ в словаре?

Comment: То, что указано в примере :)